# Reusable UILabel styles in Swift, Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uilabel, xcode6.4

Is there an easier way of styling UILabels than making custom classes that override UILabel. Currently I have need of a bunch of styles with different font sizes and text colors.

Comment: What's wrong with setting the `font` and `textColor` attributes on a standard `UILabel`?

Comment: Do you mean individually on each and every UILabel by using the interface builder?

Comment: Well, your question doesn't mention IB. These properties obviously need to be applied in code. Alternatively you could try the `UIAppearance` protocol. It is, however, limited in Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know this is a good practice... but you could something like:

```
extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var myStyle: String {
        set {
            switch newValue  {
            case "style1":
                self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
                self.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            case "style2":
                self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32)
                self.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

            default:
                break
            }
        }
        get {
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Maybe, you should define a subclass with `@IBDesignable`. Because that shows much better preview in the IB. And, you can use `Editor > Size To Fit` or Auto Layout feature in IB.

```
@IBDesignable class StyledLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var myStyle: String = "" {
        didSet {
            switch self.myStyle {
            case "style1":
                self.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
                self.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            case "style2":
                self.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32)
                self.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Now I just need to know if it is good practice or not

Comment: The whole point of this question was to avoid using custom classes because I wanted to avoid setting the custom classes for all my UILabels :).. Preview is less important than writing less code so for now I'll stick to what you wrote before the edit

Comment: Second option (making a class) I tested and is really great. Now I can just change the class name of my custom UI and style as I want. Really helpful.